# Would like information about these files

Tags: java, file, nio

I wrote a program that goes through directories recursively; that is, it has a method that goes through all the files in a directory; if any of those files are (sub)directories, it also goes through the subdirectory's files, etc. Once my program determines that a file is not a directory, it creates a File object for it and gets certain information from that, such as how much space it takes up, etc.

I wondered if NIO Path objects would do this work any faster; I don't need the file data itself, afaik I don't need to open the file. I need the name, extension, and length. So I went about writing a new method that took a String and created a Path instead of a File.

I've run into a set of files that puzzle me. In c:\Users<name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ are 5 of these files; they're all EXE files, they're all 0 length. Doing a DOS directory listing, including one with the /AL qualifier, does not show them to be either junctions or symlinks. But if I create a Path object with one of them and then attempt to read the file's basic attributes:

```
    Path path = Paths.get(folderPath.toString(), fileName);
    BasicFileAttributes bfa = null;
    try {  bfa = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class); }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
      File testFile = new File(String.format("%s%s%s", folderPath.toString(), File.separator, fileName));
      System.out.println(String.format("Got %s even though IOException thrown: %s", testFile.getName(), ioe.getMessage()));
    }
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\ralph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\GameBarElevatedFT_Alias.exe: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:193)
  at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
  at rcutil.file.FolderWalker.walkTree(FolderWalker.java:80)
  at rcutil.file.FolderWalker.walkTree(FolderWalker.java:89)
  at rcutil.file.FolderWalker.walkTree(FolderWalker.java:89)
  at rcutil.file.FolderWalker.walkTree(FolderWalker.java:89)
  at rcutil.file.FolderWalker.walkFolder(FolderWalker.java:60)
  at rcutil.file.FolderWalker.main(FolderWalker.java:178)
```

(I will provide full code below)

I created a 0-length file with an EXE extension; it shows up in a dir listing, but not if I do dir/al. The attrib command works on my self-created test file, but not on these files. My program has no problem with this file.

So what are these animals? If I do a dir/al on junctions and symbolic links, they show up with SYMLINK and JUNCTION normally. I've found documentation on something called a Hard Link, which seems to be similar to a symbolic link; there seems to be no DOS (or other) command that displays these in a directory folder.

Does anyone have more information? I can always just go back to using java.io.File; don't know if the java.nio.file.Path is going to be faster anyway.  But now I'm curious just what these beasts are...

```
package rcutil.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

import rcutil.system.OperatingSystemUtil;

/**
 * Provides the walking of all files in a folder, recursively; instantiation requires
 * a parameter class implementing a callback to receive a method call for each file 
 * and directory encountered in the tree walk.
 * <P>The walkFolder() method in this class walks an entire directory subtree recursively,
 * making a call to the given callback class for each file and directory giving information
 * about the file or directory found. 
 * 
 * <P> TODO: convert this to the java.nio version, which I didn't know existed when
 * I wrote this.
 * @author rcook
 *
 */
public class FolderWalker
{
  FolderWalkerUser user;
  
  /**
   * Instantiate the folder walker to call back the given user for each file and directory encountered.
   * 
   * @param user
   */
  public FolderWalker(FolderWalkerUser user)
  {
    this.user = user;
  }
  
  /**
   * Start a treewalk at the given folder. Cannot be a non-directory file or a symbolic link.
   * @param givenFolderName
   * @throws Exception
   */
  public void walkFolder(String givenFolderName) throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      if (isStringEmpty(givenFolderName)) { throwIOException((givenFolderName == null ? "Null" : "Empty") + " folderPath given to FolderWalker"); }
      
      Path path = Paths.get(givenFolderName);
      File topFile = path.toFile(); // new File(givenFolderName);
      
      if (!(topFile.exists()))  { throwIOException("File <" + givenFolderName + "> given to FolderWalker does not exist"); }
      
      BasicFileAttributes bfa = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
      if (!bfa.isDirectory()) { throwIllegalArgumentException("Folder path <" + givenFolderName + "> given to FolderWalker is not a directory"); }
      if (bfa.isSymbolicLink()) { throwIllegalArgumentException("Folder path <" + givenFolderName + "> given to FolderWalker is a symbolic link"); }

//      walkTree(topFile);
      walkTree(path);
      user.afterFolderWalk(givenFolderName);
      
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      throw new IOException("Exception during FolderWalker.walkFolder() for <" + givenFolderName + ">", e);
    }
  }
  
  private void walkTree(Path folderPath) throws Exception
  {
    File folderFile = folderPath.toFile();
    user.foundFile(folderFile, true);
    String[] fileNameList = folderFile.list();
    if (fileNameList != null && fileNameList.length > 0)
    {
      for (String fileName : fileNameList)
      {
        Path path = Paths.get(folderPath.toString(), fileName);
        BasicFileAttributes bfa = null;
        try {  bfa = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class); }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
          File testFile = new File(String.format("%s%s%s", folderPath.toString(), File.separator, fileName));
          System.out.println(String.format("Got %s even though IOException thrown: %s", testFile.getName(), ioe.getMessage()));
//          ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (bfa != null)
        {
          if (bfa.isDirectory()) { walkTree(path);               }
          else                   { user.foundFile(null, false);  }      
            // BIG TODO: passing null; if we switch to Paths, do we need to change the 
            // FolderWalkerUser interface to use paths?
            // trying to avoid File when possible, on theory that doing so saves runtime
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  private void walkTree(File folder) throws Exception
  {
//    System.out.println("walkTree thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    user.foundFile(folder, true);               // users are notified of folders at the top of their subtree 
    String[] fileNameList = folder.list();
    if (fileNameList != null && fileNameList.length > 0)
    {
      for (String fileName : fileNameList)
      {
        File currentFile = new File(folder, fileName);
//        if (isSymbolicLink(currentFile)) { System.out.printf("Symbolic link: %s%n"); }
        if (currentFile.isDirectory())
        {
          walkTree(currentFile);
        }
        else
        {
          user.foundFile(currentFile, false);     // user notified of non-folder files in sequence, after their containing folder
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  private boolean isStringEmpty(String givenFolderName)
  {
    return (givenFolderName == null || givenFolderName.length() <= 0);
  }
  
  private void throwIOException(String msg) throws IOException
  {
    throw new IOException(msg);
  }

  private void throwIllegalArgumentException(String msg) throws IOException
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
  }

  private boolean isSymbolicLink(File file) throws IOException
  {
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
    if (OperatingSystemUtil.isWindows()) 
    {
      absolutePath = absolutePath.toLowerCase();
      canonicalPath = canonicalPath.toLowerCase();
    }
    return (!(absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)));
  }
  
  /**
   * for testing purposes -- echo the folder tree as we walk it.
   * @param arguments
   */
  public static void main(String ... arguments)
  {
    String startFolderName = "C:\\Users\\ralph\\AppData";
    if (arguments != null && arguments.length > 0)
    {
      startFolderName = arguments[0];
    }
    
    System.out.println("Starting walk...");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    FolderWalker walker = new FolderWalker(new FolderWalkerUser() 
                                            {
                                              int fileCount, folderCount;
                                              public void foundFile(File file, boolean isDirectory)
                                              {
//                                                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                                fileCount++;
                                              }
                                              public void afterFolderWalk(String folderName)
                                              {
//                                                System.out.println("all done, folder name " + folderName);
                                                folderCount++;
                                              }
                                            }
                                          );
    try { walker.walkFolder(startFolderName); }
    catch (Exception ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(String.format("Walk done, %5.2f seconds", elapsedTime/1000f));
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Could have been viral payloads that your antivirus stopped. Not programming related though. So off-topic here.

Comment: The `WindowsApps` folder is where information about all Windows Store apps is stored.  I have 5 of those stub files in my folder, although I am allowed to delete them (are you probing another user here?).  My guess is there is information in the secondary streams for these files that allows them to be used where only a Windows Store app would normally be allowed.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I showed and explained the programming problem related to these files. I don't know how to show it to be programming related any better than that.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your question is in the folder WindowsApps there are 5 EXE files of 0 bytes. What are these 5 particular files? And then you don't even tell us the names of the five files (you said one is `GameBarElevatedFT_Alias.exe`). How would we know? And what does it have to do with programming? Besides they may have some general metadata which you also don't really tell us anything about.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried to look up info on "secondary streams" and found NTFS "alternate streams", which I don't fully understand. They seem to be a runtime thing; there was no mention in the quick lookup I did about file entries in a folder that corresponded to them. I'm still wondering what these ARE, in Windows terminology. They seem to be some kind of file, but what kind? They aren't directories, symlinks, or junctions. They don't behave the same as 0-length files, in the java program reading them. So what are they?

Comment: I gave 8 lines of code, saying that I got an exception attempting to execute those lines on all of these files. I gave the 14 lines of Java exception, which includes the directory where the files are found. I gave the entire 180-odd line program in case someone wants to run that; they'll need to alter the directory name for their system. If none of that means "programming related" to you, I can't help. If you have some relevant clarification to ask for -- like what the general metadata is and how to find it -- that might be useful.

Comment: On my machine, they seem to be ordinary 0-length files.  I can open them, I can delete them.  However, they are several days old.  Perhaps yours are still "in use".

Comment: Your question isn't about your code. It is about 5 specific files. Off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files are related to aliases of Windows Store Apps. These allow launching Windows Store programs from the command line. You can see aliases and turn alias on/off here:

```
   Settings > Apps > App execution aliases
```

Any edits change the number of EXE reported in the folder:

```
dir c:\Users\{userid}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\
```

Although querying these files with `Files.readAttributes` returns an exception, you can scan them with `Files.find` which gets same information with correct privileges.

Here is an example - just pass in your directory as above and this find returns a stream of `Map.Entry<Path, BasicFileAttributes>` pair so you can read both the Path and it's attributes for each EXE:

```
public static Stream<Map.Entry<Path, BasicFileAttributes>>
find(Path dir, int maxDepth, BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> matcher, FileVisitOption... options) throws IOException {

    HashMap <Path,BasicFileAttributes> attrs = new HashMap<>();
    BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (p,a) -> (matcher == null || matcher.test(p, a)) && attrs.put(p, a) == null;

    return Files.find(dir, maxDepth, predicate, options).map(p -> Map.entry(p, attrs.remove(p)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path dir = Path.of(args[0]);

    // replace Integer.MAX_VALUE by 1 for current dir only:
    try(var x = find(dir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p,a)-> p.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".exe"))) {
        x.forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey().toString()+" => "
                          +(entry.getValue().isDirectory() ? "DIR" : String.valueOf(entry.getValue().size()))));
    }
}
```

Use `Files.find/walk` / NIO for directory scans, for larger directory trees NIO is significantly quicker than repeated `File.list()` calls.